# How to charge titanium dioxide particles for a DIY e-paper capsule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, colloids, chemical-engineering

I'm trying to make a single e-paper capsule (1 cm × 1 cm) at home. At first, I tried to charge the $\ce{TiO2}$ particles by putting them in $\ce{H2O}$ with $\ce{NaOH}$ and then putting that whole solution in baby oil, but it turns out I shouldn't have any water in the whole process. I also tried adding a surfactant (liquid soap) but it also has water. Water is a problem because it forms micelles around the $\ce{TiO2}$ particles and prevents proper spreading. How do I charge the $\ce{TiO2}$ particles without water (and $\ce{NaOH}$). What oil-soluble surfactant I can use that doesn't contain water? Does anyone know any details about how the chemicals of the e-paper display work?

I researched a lot and it turns out the big companies use complicated processes and mixing different chemicals with expensive lab machines to produce the desired charged $\ce{TiO2}$ solution. Is there any way I can do it at home?

---

From the abstract of an article describing a TiO2 preparation protocol$^1$:

> It was found that highly charged TiO2 particles could be prepared by milling 1.0 g of TiO2 particles, 0.5 g of silane additive as a charge controlling agent and 0.5 g of dispersant in 100 mL of cyclohexanone as a suspension fluid for 8–10 h using pot mill, followed by treatment with 0.4 g of acetic acid.

What is a common silane additive used as a charge controlling agent? And what would be an appropriate dispersant here?

Can anyone here recommend additional preparation protocols, perhaps something that might be considered a "standard recipe"?

**References**

1. Park, Lee, Park, Jin, Choi, Hae, Han, Yoon Soo, Kwon, Younghwan, Choi, Hyung. Fabrication of charged particles for electrophoretic display. 
   Current Applied Physics 6(4):644-648.

Comment: Why would *"big companies use complicated processes and mixing different chemicals with expensive lab machines to produce the desired charged TiO2 solution"* if there was an easy and cheap way to do it?

Comment: True, but I spent my whole summer vacation researching and experiment and it's hard to let go.

Comment: At the beginning, it was as easy as mixing H2O, NaOH and TiO2, that was the first step. But then I learned that I shouldn't have any H2O anywhere, and it turns out, charging TiO2 particles without water is hard.

Comment: Start by figuring out the composition of the commercial stuff. Then reverse engineer...

Comment: The engineering is already known, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232414208_Fabrication_of_charged_particles_for_electrophoretic_display it's just too complicated for a 17 year old to do at home without the budget and proper equipment. My last option is to find charged TiO2 online to buy, or very cheap e-paper display.

Comment: It is extremely cool that you are pursuing this, and you may yet find some way to make something similar work. You might want to look inside that article for more details, unfortunately I can't help you with that.

Comment: The following product is listed as a "charge control agent for toner cartridges": https://www.gelest.com/product/SID3395.6/

Comment: You have regular and uniform $\ce{TiO2}$ nano-particles? Those aren't too easy to come by either...

Comment: @StianYttervik I asked people at ClearInk and E-Ink and they said their process of making the fluid is a trade secret and they don't share it just like that. There are a few documents leaked though and it's pretty complicated. It requires special machines and so on...

Comment: Heh, yeah I should think so. But it isn't that complicated to just make the nano particles (the regular and uniform bit can be, though) - it could be out of reach of regular household items. There are pyrolysis routes that I am vaguely aware of. If there is a university nearby, I'd try to ask one of the chemistry professors. The method you describe in the post is... interesting. Silane ($\ce{SiH_4(g)}$) is a quite explosive gas, I wouldn't try milling it without having the atmosphere in order.

Comment: @StianYttervik I think that recipe refers to a substituted silane, dispersed in solvent, and not silane gas.